# At the beginning of the 'udemy-react' course, there are some settings that are not working. - bash portion of nvm setup

Tags: bash, terminal, nvm

the next list is following the course settings. I'm just following that
I'm a beginner at Mac computers. I used to deal with design programs such as pigma. (mac os monterey )

1. vscode install
2. open vscode
3. shall command : install 'code'command in path
4. open terminal
5. nvm install => curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.4/install.sh | bash
6. I typed in terminal => command -v nvm
7. noting show
8. I typed in terminal => nao ~/.bash_profile
9. I typed ' source ~/.bashrc ' last in bash_profile
10. again typed command - v nvm
11. and just showed nvm
12. just show nvm  ( I don't know this is normal or.. wrong - I followed the curriculum, but it appeared differently. There is not one thing that can be copied differently in the process. It's very simple. However, the results are different. I don't know why. Of course, I asked the process, but there is no answer. I think it's because it's been about a year. )
13. and I just typed source ~/.bash_profile

14.. and.. wow. showed
**-bash: bash_env: command not found
-bash: /Users/imac/.bashrc: No such file or directory**
(I found it completely different from the one on the lecture screen.)
why doese this happen?
 [process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JIgi.jpg)

Comment: You can't source a file, which isn't here. There is no law that you **have** to have a .bash_profile, but if you want one, you have to create it.  By any means, read the section titled _INVOCATION_ in _man bash_. When you are configuring bash, you need to know which files are used under which conditions.

Comment: BTW, if nothing is displayed when you type `command -v nvm`, it just means that you have not included in your PATH the directory where `nvm` is located.  BTW. the command with the name `command`, that you used, is a bash internal command. It is documented in the bash man-page in the section _SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS_. Don't blindly type what's written in the tutorial. At least look up at those commands to get some idea what they are doing.

Comment: _I typed in terminal => nao ~/.bash_profile_ : What is `nao`?

Comment: `nao` I think is a typo for the command `nano` for editing the ~/.bash_profile file

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with line 2 of your `.bash_profile` file. So on line 2 it has:

```
bash_env
```

however, that is not a valid bash command or function.

I imagine if you delete line 2, save the file and run `source ~/.bash_profile` that will fix your problem.

I believe that its failing on that and not getting any further into your file and thus not adding nvm onto your path, and that fixing that `bash_env` will then help you out!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind answer. wow. it's great.i can use it now. I wanna to check the answer. But I didn't make it in my reputation.

Comment: Yay! Glad that helped you out!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should check which shell you are using by:

```
echo $SHELL
```

macOS Monterey by default is using `zsh` as shell, which the above command should output:

```
/bin/zsh
```

To use `bash` as shell to execute the exercise in your question, you can switch to `bash` by:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

To revert back to `zsh`, run this command:

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

Remember to relaunch the Terminal every time you switched the shell.